# jQuery dynamic textbox issues

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to generate textboxes dynamically on my webpage.  I got it working using an example that I found, but I'm having trouble with a 'Remove' button that I am adding to each row.

Firebug is giving me a syntax error on the last line, but I can't figure out why it's complaining.

Here is the jQuery function:

```
$(document).on('ready', function () {

    var counter = 2;

    $("#addButton").click(function () {
        if(counter>10){
            alert("Only 10 learning objectives allowed per page.");
            return false;
        }   

        var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
             .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
        newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Page Objective ' + counter + ' : </label>' +
            '<input type="text" name="tbObjective' + counter +
            '" id="tbObjective' + counter + '" value="" >' +
            '<input type="button" value="Remove Objective" class="removeObjective">').click(function() {
                alert('fired');
                $(this).remove();
            });
    });
        newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
        counter++;
    });

    $("#removeButton").click(function () {
        alert('fired');
        if(counter==1){
            alert("No more textbox to remove");
            return false;
        }   
        counter--;
        $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();
    });

    $(".removeObjective").click(function () {
        alert('fired');
        var $id = $(this);
        $($id).remove();
    });

});   //Firebug is showing a syntax error here?
```

Comment: Not sure it will matter but change $id to id javascript variables don't use the $ identifier. Also lose the on_click in the button itself, it's not needed with jQuery

Comment: Above posted is incorrect. It's common convention to prepend a jQuery object with a $ to keep track of its type. It's legal to include it in  a javascript variable name. That being said, right AFTER you define it, you don't need to re-wrap it in $(), just $id.remove() is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What was line 20 had an extra set of `]);` which prematurely closed the containing ready callback.

This code is syntactically correct now:

```
$(document).on('ready', function () {

    var counter = 2;

    $("#addButton").click(function () {
        if(counter>10){
            alert("Only 10 learning objectives allowed per page.");
            return false;
        }   

        var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div'))
             .attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
        newTextBoxDiv.after().html('<label>Page Objective ' + counter + ' : </label>' +
            '<input type="text" name="tbObjective' + counter +
            '" id="tbObjective' + counter + '" value="" >' +
            '<input type="button" value="Remove Objective" class="removeObjective">').click(function() {
                alert('fired');
                $(this).remove();
            });
        newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
        counter++;
    });

    $("#removeButton").click(function () {
        alert('fired');
        if(counter==1){
            alert("No more textbox to remove");
            return false;
        }   
        counter--;
        $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();
    });

    $(".removeObjective").click(function () {
        alert('fired');
        var $id = $(this);
        $($id).remove();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the whole point of the counter is to give unique ID's to the textboxes, you do not need to decrement it. Actually I think decrementing it will cause problems.

instead of

```
($this).remove
```

use

```
$('#TextBoxDiv' + counter).remove();
```